# Bluetooth device discovery is not working properly on android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am building an app that requires communicating with another device via bluetooth , and i am using the following code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html.

The code runs without any errors , But the devices are not discovered even when visibility is turned on on the nearby device, But suddenly gets discovered when i go to bluetooth settings manually on my phone after i open the app ,I have tested this on android 6.0 and Android 4.4.2,Any help will be appreciated ! Code is given below

```
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context context;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkin);
        context=getApplicationContext();
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mBluetoothAdapter   = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        listItems.add("Hello");
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Intent discoverableIntent = new
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;


// Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                listItems.add(device.getName());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(device.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("AnoudisBT")) {
                    pairDevice(device);
                    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                }
            }
            if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.d("antinom","Started Scan");
            }
        }
    };

    private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "Start Pairing...");

            Method m = device.getClass()
                    .getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            Log.d("TAG", "Pairing finished.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: please use system BT setting views first, to figure out whether the problem from your codes.

Comment: @Jiang please elaborate , I did not understand ! If you are referring to the system Bluetooth settings , I have checked !